# SQL Query Pivot Table Rows into Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have data like this which I want to create matrix result like rows into column.

```
Seq JobNo       TrnDate     TrnHour
1   J-000198    2016-04-02  5
2   J-000198    2016-04-03  4
3   J-000198    2016-04-04  8
4   J-000198    2016-04-05  7
5   J-000198    2016-04-06  2
6   J-000198    2016-04-07  3
7   J-000198    2016-04-08  6
```

On 2016-04-02 TrnDate the day was Saturday and so on. I want result like this through sql query and populate in gridview to add/edit by a user.

```
Saturday Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
02       03     04     05      06        07       08
5        4      8      7       2         3        6
```

Is this possible? Please help. Thanks

Edited---------

Its a complete month entries for each JobNo. It makes sum for each day. For example if I add one more row like this it make sum for Saturday date 9+2=11 and hours 5+5=10. I want it to be separate for each week.

```
Seq JobNo       TrnDate     TrnHour
8   J-000198    2016-04-09  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col, [Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], 
       [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday]
FROM (
  SELECT JobNo, x.col, x.val,
         DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TrnDate) AS d
  FROM mytable
  CROSS APPLY (
     VALUES ('Hour', TrnHour), 
            ('Day', DATEPART(dd, TrnDate))) x(col, val)  
) AS src
PIVOT (SUM(val) FOR d IN ([Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], 
                          [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])) AS pvt
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a51f/1)

To account for different weeks you have to include the week number in the `SELECT` clause of the query used to generate the source table of the `PIVOT` operation:

```
SELECT col, w, [Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday]
FROM (
  SELECT JobNo, x.col, x.val, 
         DATEPART(WEEK, TrnDate) AS w,
         DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TrnDate) AS d
  FROM mytable
  CROSS APPLY (
     VALUES ('Hour', TrnHour), ('Day', DATEPART(dd, TrnDate))) x(col, val)   
  ) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(val) FOR d IN ([Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], 
                              [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])) AS pvt
ORDER BY w, col
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1be3/1)

Comment: Thank you for reply Giorgos Betsos. I edited my post. I have several rows means complete month rows. I want to keep seperate result for each week but it summarize the values

Comment: @Raja You can easily modify the above query in order to account for separate weeks. Just add the weeknumber in the `SELECT` clause of the `src` derived table.

Comment: I couldnt do this. I get week number like this datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, TrnDate)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 but dont know how to put into your query

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
SELECT info, [Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday], [Friday]
FROM (
    SELECT 'Total Hour' as info, JobNo, trnHour,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TrnDate) AS d FROM JobTable   
    union all
    SELECT 'Date' info,JobNo, datepart(day,TrnDate) as trnHour,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,TrnDate) AS d FROM JobTable 
) AS src
PIVOT (SUM(trnHour) FOR d IN ([Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],[Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])) AS pvt
```

Week wise.

```
SELECT [week],info, [Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday], [Friday]
FROM (
    SELECT 'Total Hour' as info, JobNo, trnHour,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TrnDate) AS d,datepart(week,TrnDate) [week] FROM JobTable 
    union all
    SELECT 'Date' info,JobNo, datepart(day,TrnDate) as trnHour,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,TrnDate) AS d,datepart(week,TrnDate) [week] FROM JobTable   
) AS src
PIVOT (SUM(trnHour) FOR d IN ([Saturday], [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],[Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])) AS pvt
```

Comment: Missing a bracket on [Wednesday].  FYI

Comment: @Raja query return what u want thats it.

Comment: @saddam_msp Its not what I want to be returned. I mentioned above what is the requirement. Please go through it if you willing to reply. Thanks

Comment: hey @Raja please check i have edited for week wise as per you hv axpected.